# reverting cell value to a specific formula if cell is blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets/Script: 
I want to make it so, that a whole range (say A1:H30) of Sheet1 gets modified in a way that if an individual cell is empty, it gets a formula like =Sheet2!A1 to =Sheet2!H30. But should a user put something into the cell, it shall overwrite the formula of that cell to the new value.

I have read that this should be a case for onedit(e) with old and newvalue but I can't quite get my head around the implementation part.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What are the specifics of your situation? Should A1:H30 be initialized that way or do they start blank.  Can you share your spreadsheet and have you tried any code of your own.

Comment: Hello Cooper, the initialization for A1:H30 is the formula (each corresponding cells value of sheet2) I dont have any workable code as I never seem to get the e.range step to be working. Thank you. :)

Comment: I hope you realize that you can not run an onEdit(e) function from the script editor.  The event trigger creates an event object that you can access when the event occurs (i.e. in this case a cell get's edited).

Comment: Personally, I use e.source.toast() a lot to debug these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast(' e.value: ' + e.value);
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet4'){return;}
  if(e.range.rowStart<31 && e.range.columnStart<9 && !e.value) { //if in the range of A1:H30 and new value is blank
    var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart); 
    rg.setFormula("=Sheet2!" + rg.getA1Notation());
    //e.source.toast('A1: ' + rg.getA1Notation() + ' e.value: ' + e.value);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper, I want to thank you very much for your help and your time. It is so very much appreciated, as you helped me and lots of my colleagues out. Is there any way to support your work here on this site in form of upvoting? I was just able to upvote your answer. If there's anything I can do, feel free to tell me. Wish you a very great day. :)

Comment: Good day Cooper,
sorry to bother you again. The code you provided works very well. I just wanted to ask if there is a way to let the code put in the rg.setFormula alreaydy after "delete" has been pressed once? Because as it is now, we have to press delete twice in order for it to register the onedit. Thank you very much.